# Pass a string variable to spread function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make a function which I pass a string variable to dplyr pipeline but having some problem. Like the following

```
col_spread = "speed".
```

In select(), I can use get(col_spread) to select the column named speed.

```
df %>% select(get(col_spread))
```

However, when I am using spread function in dplyr

```
df %>% spread(key = Key_col, value = get(col_spread)) 
Error: Invalid column specification
```

It doesn't work.

Is NSE the only way to go? If so, what should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `spread_` by any chance? Also, there is also `select_`

Comment: Note the normal versions _are_ the NSE versions; the `*_` versions are the SE (standard evaluation) ones. [Reading.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)

Answer (score 3):

Actually `get` really isn't a great idea. It would be better to use the standard evaulation version of

```
df %>% select_(col_spread)
```

and then for spread it would look like

```
df %>% spread_("Key_col", col_spread)
```

note which values are quoted and which are not. `spread_` expects two character values.